# "Connection reset on log" from Commons DBCP

Tags: apache, hibernate, spring, datasource

I am using Spring, Hibernate for CRUD operations and using Apache 'BasicDataSource' for connection pooling
Now the problem is when use below following configuration in datasource

```
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
```

than after using all connections I m getting Error of "Connection reset on log" but it takes long time to get back.

And if I m removing following lines from datasource

```
   <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
```

And adding below line to SessionFactory(hibernateProperties)

```
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
```

than i getting no error on console but the problem is It uses the connection and close as soon as it completes.